# Material 2 Call Tooltip show Method

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to figure out to call the show and hide methods on [Material 2 Tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api) so that I can force the tool tip to show or hide it based on some condition in the component.

I have tried using `@ViewChild` to get a reference to the directive but I must be doing something wrong.

Template snippet :

```
<button md-mini-fab color="primary" mdTooltip="Menu" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="remove-record">
  <md-icon color="white">view_headline</md-icon>
  </button>
```

Component Snippet:

```
export class RackAverageComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(MdTooltip) save;

    ngOnInit() {
       this.save.show();
   }
}
```

It seems like the directive in the template isn't getting associated with the component. Not sure if I am using `@ViewChild` correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give an id to tooltip.

Change your template to this:

```
<button md-mini-fab color="primary" 
              #tooltip="mdTooltip" [mdTooltip]="'Menu'" 
              [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="remove-record">
  <md-icon color="white">view_headline</md-icon>
```

... and acces the tooltip using `ViewChild` and display after view is initialized:

```
@ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip:MdTooltip;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tooltip.show ();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get a reference to the template element for @ViewChild, you should add a local template variable, as in following:
**HTML**

```
   <button #myTooltip md-mini-fab color="primary" mdTooltip="Menu" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="remove-record">
          <md-icon color="white">view_headline</md-icon>
    </button>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class RackAverageComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(myTooltip) save;
.....
}
```